# How to Pass Parameter Values at Runtime in Informatica Mapping Parameter

Tags: unix, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have a scenario like we need to load data from **source file** to **target table** from a particular date [like LOAD_DATE], So I’ll create a mapping parameter for LOAD_DATE and pass that in Source Qualifier query. My query looks like this.

```
SELECT * FROM my_TABLE where DATE >= ‘$$LOAD_DATE’
```

So here I need to pass parameter values for **‘$$LOAD_DATE’** from **another external database**. I know that I need to pass the values from the Parameter file.

But my requirement is not to hardcore the values in the Parameter file but to feed it in runtime from **another database**. I will appreciate your help and thoughts on this.

Answer (score 1):

You dont have to hardcode.
You can do it like this -
option 1. Create a mapping to create the param file in particular format.

- Read for the other DB.
- In expression transformation create below port which will generate actual param string. Pls note, we need to add new line so its recognized like a actual param file.

```
out_str = '[<<name of folder . name of workflow or sessoin>>]' || chr(12) ||
   '$$LOAD_DATE='|||| CHR(39) ||<<date value from another DB>>|| CHR(39)
```

- Then link above port to a flat file target. Name the output file as session_param.txt or whatever suitable. Pls make sure the parameter is generated correctly.

Use above file as a parameter file in your actual workflow.

Option 2 - You can join another table with original table flow. This can be difficult and need to change existing mapping.

- Join the another table from another DB with main table based on a dummy condition. make sure you get distinct values of LOAD_DATE  from another table. Make sure you always have 1 value from this DB.
- Once you have the LOAD_DATE field from another table, you can use it in filter transformation to filter the data.
- After this point you can add your original mapping.
  Whole mapping should be like this-

```
SQ_MAIN_TABLE ----------------------->|
sq_ANOTHER_TABLE --DISTINCT_LOAD_DT-->JNR--FIL on LOAD_DT --><<your mapping logic>>
```